# rows with max value

Tags: sql

I'm wanting to retrieve all rows and columns which contain the MAX value in one column.

For example: 3 columns - ID (not unique), name, age
I'm wanting all rows and columns which contain the max value in age.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done till now..? Pls share your code. Have a look at [MAX](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE age = (SELECT MAX(age) FROM table)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table where value=max(value)
```

Maybe you need to exchange where with having